# Put tables in one or several database files? (Bookings application)

Tags: android, database, datamodel

I wonder when to use several tables in the same database file, and when to use multiple files?  For example a separate database file for each table. What are the advantages and disadvantages?

I have "places", "persons" and "bookings". A person is booked to be in one place (at a certain time). Since there are some many-to- relations between them, they need to be in separate tables. Btw, this is a common task, so I wonder if anyone has links to examples or suggestions on how to solve it in the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is simple, and can be perfectly implemented using 3 tables in the same database. If you use a SQLite database, this database would be one file.

There is no benefit here in creating several files/databases. It would only bring more complexity (and even slightly impact performance/startup time because you would need to open 3 db files)

You can find a tutorial on how to use SQLite (which is the best option if you want to store the data locally on the user device) with Android [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android).

Comment: Okay, thanks. What about coordinating it with other existing databases, such as the contact list of the phone? And exporting bookings to the calendar? Do separate databases have advantages then?

Comment: No, I still don't see an advantage in splitting your database. The external data you will read (Contacts) and write (Calendar events) will not be accessed using SQL (but rather via Android APIs). You will get the contact list and insert the contacts into you own databse. So it has no impact on you own database structure.